# Ссылки при аяксе

Tags: ajax, javascript

При переходе аяксом на некоторых сайтах, и вконтакте так же, сохраняются нормальные url без хэшей. С хэшами нормально делаю, все красиво, а вот чтобы при переходе ссылки оставались вида /item/56 не получается. Подскажите может статью какую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Введение в HTML5 History APIе](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)
- [A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html)

Answer (score 6):

поддержка HTML5 History API для старых браузеров, нет ничего лучше этой библы, полностью интегрируется в браузер. http://code.spb-piksel.ru/?history.latest.zip или https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API попробуйте не пожалеете.

Библиотека которая не добавляет ненужные методы заставляя их изучать, а оперирует по спецификации w3c, по интерфейсу History.

Для примера могу привести короткий код как с ней работать.

По принципу мы работаем с HTML5 History API так как описано например тут http://htmlbook.ru/html5/history или по спецификации http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#the-history-interface

То-есть коротенький пример:

на чистом JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                // функция для ссылок обрабатывается при клике на ссылку
                function handlerAnchors() {
                    // заносим ссылку в историю
                    history.pushState( null, null, this.href );

                    // тут можете вызвать подгруздку данных и т.п.

                    // не даем выполнить действие по умолчанию
                    return false;
                }

                // ищем все ссылки
                var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

                // вешаем события на все ссылки в нашем документе
                for( var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++ ) {
                    anchors[ i ].onclick = handlerAnchors;
                }

                // вешаем событие на popstate которое срабатывает
                // при нажатии back/forward в браузере
                window.onpopstate = function( e ) {

                    // получаем нормальный объект Location

                    /*
                    * заметьте, это единственная разница при работе с данной
                    * библиотекой, так как объект document.location нельзя
                    * перезагрузить, поэтому библиотека history возвращает
                    * сформированный "location" объект внутри объекта
                    * window.history, поэтому получаем его из "history.location".
                    * Для браузеров поддерживающих "history.pushState" получаем
                    * сформированный объект "location" с обычного "document.location".
                    */
                    var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;

                    // тут можете вызвать подгруздку данных и т.п.

                    // просто сообщение
                    alert( "Мы вернулись на страницу со ссылкой: " +
                                                   returnLocation.href );
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/mylink.html">My Link</a>
        <a href="/otherlink.html">Other Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

А тепер показываю пример в связке с jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                // ищем все ссылки и вешаем события на все ссылки в нашем документе
                $("a").click(function() {
                    // заносим ссылку в историю
                    history.pushState( null, null, this.href );

                    // тут можете вызвать подгруздку данных и т.п.

                    // не даем выполнить действие по умолчанию
                    return false;
                });

                // вешаем событие на popstate которое срабатывает
                // при нажатии back/forward в браузере
                $( window ).bind( "popstate", function( e ) {

                    // получаем нормальный объект Location

                    /*
                    * заметьте, это единственная разница при работе с данной
                    * библиотекой, так как объект document.location нельзя
                    * перезагрузить, поэтому библиотека history возвращает
                    * сформированный "location" объект внутри объекта
                    * window.history, поэтому получаем его из "history.location".
                    * Для браузеров поддерживающих "history.pushState" получаем
                    * сформированный объект "location" с обычного "document.location".
                    */
                    var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;

                    // тут можете вызвать подгруздку данных и т.п.

                    // просто сообщение
                    alert( "Мы вернулись на страницу со ссылкой: " +
                                                   returnLocation.href );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/mylink.html">My Link</a>
        <a href="/otherlink.html">Other Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ок, подсказываем: [введение в HTML5 History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/).